# How to pause auto scroll div when touch on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I figured out how to auto scroll a div block but I couldn't find a way to stop the auto scroll when someone press and hold on mobile. Any suggestion? My javascript is below.

```js
function ScrollDiv() {

  if (document.getElementById('data').scrollTop < (document.getElementById('data').scrollHeight - document.getElementById('data').offsetHeight)) {
    -1
    document.getElementById('data').scrollTop = document.getElementById('data').
    scrollTop + 1
  } else {
    document.getElementById('data').scrollTop = 0;
  }
}

setInterval(ScrollDiv, 25)
```

Comment: What's that `-1` wandering around? Also know that by doing `document.getElementById('data')` you're forcing the DOM parser for an entire document lookup for that element - multiple times, unnecessarily. Store a reference inside a variable and use that variable instead.

Comment: Why don't you use the native `Element.scrollTo()` with `behavior: 'smooth'` option? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo and see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Comment: I was actually found this code by someone else I'm still new with JavaScript. But yeah, i will try the native that you just suggested